# Pandas CategoricalDtype causing IndexError when attempting to write to Excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a dataframe that I want to custom sort. I am using `pandas` `CategoricalDtype` as shown in the second method here https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-a-custom-sort-on-pandas-dataframe-ac18e7ea5320.
When I try to write the results to an Excel workbook using `openpyxl`, I get this error `IndexError: string index out of range`.
Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cloth_id': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006],
    'size': ['S', 'XL', 'M', 'XS', 'L', 'S'],
})

cat_size_order = CategoricalDtype(
    ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'], 
    ordered=True
)

df['size'] = df['size'].astype(cat_size_order)
   
df.sort_values('size', inplace=True)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save("sort_test.xlsx")
```

Here is the whole traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users...\untitled0.py", line 30, in <module>
    for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\dataframe.py", line 58, in dataframe_to_rows
    row = [data[j][idx] for j in range(ncols)]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\dataframe.py", line 58, in <listcomp>
    row = [data[j][idx] for j in range(ncols)]

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it? Is this a `openpyxl` bug?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem after sort_value：

```
 df['size'] = df['size'].astype(str)
```